# rails alternative to enum and view integration

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

rails doesn't offer `ENUM` types, but I do need a data member which can accept only five values.     Moreover, I want it to be integrated automatically with the Rails Forms Helper: `select_tag`.
What's the right solution to my situation?

P.S, I'd rather not to use external plugins, if built-in and neat solution exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrated automatically" with the form helper? In order to do that you'd need to create an association. Making an association that isn't an actual table is possible, but might it just be easier to provide the list of allowable values?

Comment: so I could in the controller do: @forum = Forum.new(params[:forum]) and read it automatically like the others fields.

Comment: You still could; that's not relevant to where the values are defined: it's just a string from a form.

Comment: ok, write it as an answer and I will accept that. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I keep functionality like this as close to where it's used as possible.

If the values are used by a single model, just keep them in the model, e.g., if users have certain possible types, and only those types, it might look something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = %w{guest, paid, admin}

  # Plus validation on the `type` field.
  # Maybe plus a setter override that also validates.
end
```

When you need to refer to those types elsewhere, like as allowable values in a select:

```
User::TYPES
```

There are a number of valuable tweaks around this, like providing decorators to make them "human readable" (capitalized, spaced, whatever) or metaprogramming methods to allow things like:

```
user.is_guest?   # Or...
user.make_guest! # Or...
user.guest!
```

I use my own small gem for this functionality because it's often the case that a full-blown association is just too much and provides no value. It allows things like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  simple_enum :user_type, %w{guest, paid, admin}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the tip from this [blog post](http://www.kensodev.com/2012/05/08/the-simplest-enum-you-will-ever-find-for-your-activerecord-models/),  which offers a very simple approach.
You can set in on your model and then use it on your controller or views.
In this case it will map the status with integers.

```
STATUS = { pending: 0, active: 1, inactive: 2, deleted: 3 }

def status
  STATUS.key(read_attribute(:status))
end

def status=(s)
  write_attribute(:status, STATUS[s])
end
```

Comment: This approach has a couple of advantages. The biggest *dis*-advantage, at least for me, is that the DB becomes a bit less readable if looking at the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.1 has enums. I just upgraded to the beta and it's working like a charm!

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

I tried active_enum gem, which is great, but it's not compatible with rails 4. The solution from Paulo works pretty well and you can extract the enum into a concern if you want, but it just started getting too heavy for me so I rather upgraded!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define the Enum as a helper in ApplicationHelper

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def select_range
    %w{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
  end
end
```

Then in view you can call `select_range` freely.

Comment: I would argue that if the enum is tied directly to a particular model or models that it belongs somewhere else rather than in a helper. Either in the model, or in something mixed in to the models.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I understand your point but can't see that from the question. If model involved, it can still be defined in helper, or as a method in model, as long as details provided.

Comment: Yes, it *could* be defined in a helper, or as an immediate list in the view, or... but *why* would you define it anywhere else than in the model where it's used? Keeping it local to its related classes would be considered a best practice (e.g., see the Rails Anti-Patterns book). Allowable values are tied explicitly to the model, and IMO that dependency should be explicit in the code as well. Since you also need to validate input values keeping them anywhere but in the model or a mixin just confuses things.